# HTML5 Drag & Drop Video Playlist

Tags: html, audio, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a client project that needs to be able to have video files that can be moved to a playlist via drag and drop. Each video is only a few seconds long - think of it as a kind of visual beat mixer. I can get the videos to drag and drop, but I'm having a hard time finding something that will let me add the video to a playlist. Does anyone have any experience with this or relevant examples from around the web?

Answer (score 0):

you may have to keep the playlist in an array in javascript or something. then every time there's a drag and drop (addition or deletion), insert or delete the element in the list, then repopulate your display with the updated list. I hope this helps.